# How to set gradient color for a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to set the gradient color of a specific tab.It contains a gradient color from first tab to last tab.How can I set this.
For that I used the below code

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

      $('.gradient_me').each( function(index) {
          var color = 255-index*75;
          $(this).css('background', 'rgb('+color+', 0, 0)');
      });
  });
```

But the problem is one tab contains only one color.I want gradient color from first to last tab.How can I do this?

Comment: `But the problem is one tab contains only one color.`  can u elaborate this.. i check the fiddle and tabs header has 3 different color

Comment: @bipen-I want gradient color for the each tab.In the demo you can see that the tabs are gradient.But inside a tab,its not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy!

All you need is a linear gradient CSS rule.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

      $('.gradient_me').each( function(index) {
          var color = 'rgb(' + (255-index*75) + ', 0, 0)';
          var color2 = 'rgb(' + (255-index*75 - 75) + ', 0, 0)';
          $(this).css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(left, '+color+', ' + color2 +')');
          $(this).css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, '+color+', ' + color2 +')');
          $(this).css('background', '-ms-linear-gradient(left, '+color+', ' + color2 +')');
          $(this).css('background', '-o-linear-gradient(left, '+color+', ' + color2 +')');
          $(this).css('background', 'linear-gradient(left, '+color+', ' + color2 +')');

      });
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5zfyU/8/

Comment: Do you want me to code for you? I gave you the hint how to do what you want. The code can easily be adapted to your needs. Either do it yourself or have another job in which you're competent.